# Get controller and action of route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to resolve the controller name and action which are configured for a route

I have a route:

```
Route::get('/somePage','SomeController@someAction');
```

Can I get the controller name and action using something like:

```
resolve('/somepage');
```

to receive the same result which I can get from `Route::current()->getActionName()`

```
App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@someAction
```

Comment: Do you have any issues with `Route::current()->getActionName()`?

Comment: There is `route()` helper by the way

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why do you need to do this? Are you sure there's no better solution to your original problem?

Comment: I'm building authorization system and I want to check if the user has permission for specific URL before the page is resolved. that is why I want to resolve the name of the controller and the action to see if the user has permissions for the page

Comment: IMHO `request()->route()->getAction()` is enough for nearly everybody, you can call it on the controller constructor or in a middleware. There is a reason if a function like you asked does not exist yet in the laravel codebase: nobody needs it. And you did not explained why do you need it. So until explained it is an XY problem for me also.

Comment: I still don't really understand. The permissions are related to route middleware. The action is basically a controller function. The both are route properties so getting the action is probably secondary. I would guess the real question here is getting the route instance given a url

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
function getAction($uri, $method) {
        $route = collect(Route::getRoutes())
            ->filter(function($route) use($uri, $method){
            return $route->getUri() === $uri && 
                    in_array($method, $route->getMethods());
        })->first();
        return $route ? $route->getAction() : null;
}
```

Usage:

```
$action = getAction('posts', 'GET');
```

Alternatively:

```
$request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::create('posts', 'GET');
$action = Route::getRoutes()->match($request)->getAction();
```

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. The only problem was that `$route->getUri()` doesn't exist and `$route->url` have to be used. The alternative solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PlamenVasilev What version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: You can check what API's are supported - https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html

Answer (score 0):

I usually use **route('somePageRoute')** method but first name the route

```
Route::get('/somePage','SomeController@someAction')->name('somePageRoute');
```

Comment: `route()` function returns a url like `http://domain/someAction` I want the controller name and the action name, not the URL

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can get controller name and action by this

```
request()->route()->getAction()
```

Comment: I want it for specific route, not for the current one!